# Oracle Forms 6i master-detail question from a painfully new newbie

Tags: master-detail, oracleforms

I have a form that contains 3 blocks (block a, b, c). There is a master-detail relationship between b (detail) and c (master).

Data-flow:   you enter an ID in block a, which in turn populates block c and corresponding details in block b. Control goes immediately to block c.

Objective: I need to be able to update details of block b.

Issue: I cannot navigate to block b.

Keep in Mind: --In the Property Palette Keyboard Navigable is set to "Yes"
              --Insert Allowed and Update Allowed are set to "Yes."

If someone could respond ASAP I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

coud you give more details on issue:

are you able to enter new data into **b** elements on canvas, or you can't even move focus to that elements ?

If you are, do you do commit and happens nothing or some sort of error occures ?